# Общий конфигурационный файл для дочерних проектов Java(Maven)

Tags: java, maven, configuration

я имею следующую структуру проекта:

```
ServerSide
    databaseserver
        ...
        pom.xml
    gameserver
        ...
        pom.xml
    pom.xml
    serverSide.properties
```

Мне хотелось бы не дублировать конфиг *serverSide* в папки ресурсов gameserver и databaseserver, а хранить его там где он расположен выше в структуре. Но когда я пытаюсь прочесть из него данные, запустив приложение из IntelijIdea, все работает замечательно, но стоит мне собрать .jar, как его сражу же не оказывается .jar файла... Вот пример кода считывания:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try (InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("databaseserver/../serverSide.properties"))) {
    properties.load(inputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("file with server properties was not read.");
}
```

Когда запускаю собранный jar, то как раз-таки и получаю мое исключение:

```
file with server properties was not read.
```

Сервер собирается при помощи:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

Родительский .pom файл:

```
...

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ru.servers</groupId>
<artifactId>serverside</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<modules>
    <module>gameserver</module>
    <module>databaseserver</module>
</modules>

<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>serverside</name>

...
```

Databaseserver pom файл:

```
...

<parent>
    <artifactId>serverside</artifactId>
    <groupId>ru.servers</groupId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>databaseserver</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<properties>
    <project.java.version>1.8</project.java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${project.java.version}</source>
                <target>${project.java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>DatabaseServer</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>ru.servers.databaseserver.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

...
```

Уже и не знаю что пробовать делать... Может поможет с этим или хотя бы подскажет в какой стороне стоит искать решение?

Answer (score 1):

Можно его вынести в отдельный модуль и этот модуль подключать к другим как зависимость, тогда ресурс станет как бы общедоступным.